using git on Ubuntu20.04.6 with symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: __gmpz_limbs_write
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, and I had the following error when using git:
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: __gmpz_limbs_write

Following some similar questions, I checked the dependencies of libgnutls.so.30, which is a hyperlink of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.27.0:
ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffef73f2000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f8173d92000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f8173d71000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f8173bef000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f8173bd9000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f8173b9f000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f8173b68000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f8173ae2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f81738f0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f81740b5000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f81738e4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f81738de000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f81738bb000)

And I could trace back to libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.
What should I do with libgmp that caused the problem?
libgmp.so.10.4.0 is pointed to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0.
And here is Git version 2.25.1

FWIW you can check for the presence of the symbol definition with something like nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0 | grep limbs

nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0 | grep limbs   000000000001db70 T __gmpz_limbs_finish 000000000001dbb0 T __gmpz_limbs_modify 000000000001dbd0 T __gmpz_limbs_read 000000000001dbe0 T __gmpz_limbs_write 00000000000192e0 T __gmpz_prodlimbs

nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep limbs                  U __gmpz_limbs_finish                  U __gmpz_limbs_modify                  U __gmpz_limbs_read                  U __gmpz_limbs_write                  U _nettle_gmp_alloc_limbs                  U _nettle_gmp_free_limbs                  U _nettle_mpz_limbs_copy  use the same command for libgnutls.so.30

So it looks like the symbol is indeed defined (T) - did you actually run ldd on  /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https itself to check that it links the expected /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0?

You can check that in fact the symbol is not available in libgmp with.
In my case, in Ubuntu 24.04 the symbol is available in libgmp.so.10:
# nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 | grep __gmpz_limbs_write
000000000001a7e0 T __gmpz_limbs_write

But interestingly in Ubuntu 24.04 libgnutls does not require the enough the __gmpz_limbs_write symbol, just the read one:
# nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep __gmpz_limbs
                 U __gmpz_limbs_read

So in your case it looks like a version mismatch.
So you can fix git or libgmp, let's try to fix the libgmp.
Look for the specific version of libgmp, in my case:
ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 ene 17  2022 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.4.1

If you have locate enabled look in the system because probabably you will already have different versions of libgmp all around:
# locate libgmp.so.10

Look one of those versions that has the symbol, and then try loading git using that version:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<other_libgmp> git

Other alternative is to look for an updated libgmp version in the official repo (in 10.4.1 the symbol is included).
I hope that this helps.
